# javascript issue getElementById to modify CSS

Tags: javascript, css, getelementbyid

I have an issue about getElementById.
Here is the part of the javascript code that causes a problem:
`var elmt = document.getElementById("cardSlotsJoueur");`

```
elmt.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/backcard.png')";
```

I wanted to modify this (Css) :

```
#cardSlotsJoueur div {
```

But it actually modifies `#cardSlotsJoueur {`

Could you help me to find a way to modify the first one with getElementById ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can add an ID to the element you want to change, or you can add a CSS rule to a style sheet that uses an appropriate selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to modify the first div within the element with id=cardSlotsJoueur, you can use this:

```
var elmt = document.getElementById("cardSlotsJoueur").getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

To target `#cardSlotsJoueur div` it's better to use `querySelector` method which would retrieve children div element of the `#cardSlotsJoueur` container:

```
var elmt = document.querySelector("#cardSlotsJoueur div");
```

If you expect multiple `div` elements under the `#cardSlotsJoueur` then you need to get them all first

```
var elmt = document.querySelectorAll("#cardSlotsJoueur div");
```

and then set `backgroundImage` to each in the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for your rapidity ! It works. By the way do you know how to resize the picture that will be in the backgound ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find `div` elements within `#cardSlotsJoueur`:

```
var elmt = document.getElementById("cardSlotsJoueur");
var divs = elmt.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) { 
  divs[i].style.backgroundImage = "url('images/backcard.png')"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do what you want is to use a class with the required styling and add it to the element. But as an alternative, you can add a rule to the last style sheet, e.g.

```
function addBackground() {
  var sheets = document.styleSheets;

  // If there are no style sheets, add one
  if (!sheets.length) {
    document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
  }

  // The sheets collection is live, if a new sheet was needed, it's automatically a member
  sheets[sheets.length - 1].insertRule('#cardSlotsJoueur div{background-image:url("images/backcard.png")');
}
```

You can make it generic:

```
function addRule(ruleText) {
  var sheets = document.styleSheets;

  if (!sheets.length) {
    document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'));
  }

  sheets[sheets.length - 1].insertRule(ruleText);
}
```

and call it like:

```
addRule('#cardSlotsJoueur div{background-image:url("images/backcard.png")');
```